# To Subclass or not to Subclass, UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

So, like many people I am coming up against UITabBarController, it's *not intended for subclassing* and *must be the root view controller* peculiarities.

I have to manage the behavior of all the subviews and the natural way to do it seems to have a root view controller which they report to and which relays messages between them. In my current setup I have PBModalRootViewController which instantiates a UITabBarController and sets it as a subview. The PBModalRootViewController manages the subviews and is responsible for dismissing the modal view.
[like so http://p.twimg.com/Abu0iWDCMAAwhuy.jpg:large](http://p.twimg.com/Abu0iWDCMAAwhuy.jpg:large)

This is a pretty clean solution **but** it leads to dodgy behavior from the UITabBarController which I assume does not like being a subview. This is something I need to fix before I ship and I have a few solutions:

1. Subclass UITabBarController and deal with the potential repercussions later on.
2. Rejig the PBModalRootViewController to be a PBModalSupervisor. i.e.: make it a class that initiates the tabBarController and the subviews, returns a nice configured view and then keeps an eye on all of them for me.
   This could lead to a lot of messing around and extra pointers lying around which might be a pain to manage.
3. Simply redesign the architecture in some ingenious way which would be great, any ideas...
4. All the stuff I haven't thought of...
5. I'm doing it all wrong and need to be slapped with a trout!
6. Use NSNotificationCentre, might this get a bit messy with save, dismiss etc, still need somewhere to manage the dismissal logic.
7. Category on UITabBarController? That would be a way around the subclassing I suppose..

Comment: Hmm, looks like omnigraffle on iPad is a little broken...

Comment: Have you considered using `NSNotificationCenter` to simplify communication among the view controllers?

Answer (score 1):

I think setting up a supervisor object is definitely the way to go. It depends on what type of info you need to keep track of between the different view controllers. If it is data that each controller needs to know about and/or display, that data needs to be separated out, and the data handling object shouldn't be handling the views directly, so it should not be a view controller.